The difference between plans and planning

This semester, she plans to improve her study habits by setting specific goals.

Vs

This semester, she is planning to improve her study habits by setting specific goals.


You can use either the present simple or present progressive to talk about future scheduled or planned events.  See here for more information.

They both mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.
However, #1 implies more certainty that she will actually follow through and improve her study habits than #2. It's probably because #1 is in the present, so right now she is planning to improve her study habits. #2 is more in the future, so she hasn't actually started planning to improve yet. It's a very subtle difference.

(1) This semester, she plans to improve her study habits by setting specific goals.


(2) This semester, she is planning to improve her study habits by setting specific goals.

